# 0.id is null or not an object, parentElement of the parentElement and IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following 3 lines of code in my web app.

```
selected_build = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.id;
var jselect = $( "#" + selected_build + " .roomc" ).children(".room");
selected_room = jselect[0].id;
```

This works in most browsers but in IE 8 I get the error

```
 '0.id' is null or not an object
```

which points to the third line of code. I assume this has something to do with parentElement only working on Elements, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume this has something to do with parentElement only working on Elements...

If IE8 doesn't have `parentElement`, since by definition you're dealing with an element as of `event.currentTarget`, you can safely use `parentNode` instead.

But as you're using jQuery *anyway*, why not...use jQuery?

```
selected_build = $(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().attr("id");
if (selected_build) {
    var jselect = $("#" + selected_build + " .roomc").children(".room");
    selected_room = jselect.attr("id");
    if (selected_room) {
        // ... use it
    }
}
```

---

Note that I'm using `.attr("id")` to get the `id`. That's because if the jQuery set is *empty*, `.attr("id")` gives you `undefined`, whereas `[0].id` gives you an error.

---

And actually — you don't need to use `id`s at all here other than at the end for `selected_room`:

```
selected_room =
    $(event.currentTarget)
        .parent().parent()
        .find(".roomc > .room")
        .attr("id");
if (selected_room) {
    // ... use it
}
```

...and I bet there's a way to hook up the event so we can avoid that `.parent().parent()`, too, which is fragile. But without seeing the structure, it's impossible to suggest something.

Comment: wow, perfect. Any idea how to convert

         `$(".roomname").text( jselect.find(".rname")[0].innerHTML );`

to jquery?

Comment: @MillerWesselhoff: Literally, `$(".roomname").text(jselect.find(".rname").html());`, but you probably want `$(".roomname").text(jselect.find(".rname").first().text());` instead (note the `.first()`). It's well worth your time reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and pays you back that time immediately. Best regards,